Why Catalan Numbers are the general solution of this combinatorics problem?
This is a problem of this year's $AMC$ $8$ math competition,

Buzz Bunny is hopping up and down a set of stairs, one step at a time. In how many ways can Buzz start on the ground, make a sequence of $6$ hops, and end up back on the ground? (For example, one sequence of hops is up-up-down-down-up-down.)

$\textbf{(A)}\ 4 \qquad \textbf{(B)}\ 5 \qquad \textbf{(C)}\ 6 \qquad \textbf{(D)}\ 8 \qquad \textbf{(E)}\ 12$

In the solutions section, of the AoPS site, solution $3$ is

These numbers are clearly the Catalan numbers. Since we have 6 steps, we need the third Catalan number, which is $\boxed{\textbf{(B)}\ 5}$. ~andliu766

I wonder how the general solution to this problem is Catalan numbers? In other words, if there are $n$ hops up and $n$ hops down, the number of ways you can make a sequence of $2n$ hops to end up to the ground is,
$$C_n=\dfrac{\large\binom{2n}n}{n+1}$$
I know that $\large\binom{2n}n$ is the number of the ways to arrange $n$ $U$'s and  $n$ $D$'s in the sequence of the letters (Where $U$ represents Up and $D$ represents Down). And among them, only those arrangements are acceptable where the number of $D$'s (following after $U$'s) does not exceed the number of the previous $U$'s. But I don't know why dividing the total number of arrangements by $n+1$ gives the desired result.

this article gives a thorough description.  Note that, in your particular case, the numbers are so small that you can count the paths without any general theory.

@lulu It is interesting to see this problem is "Dycks paths" in disguise. It actually answers my question.

Obviously there are many solutions to this.  My personal favourite is the following:
Let a path be a sequence of $n$ ups and $n$ downs.  Say a path is good if the number of downs never exceeds the number of ups.  Let $C_n$ be the number of good paths.
For $n>0$, any good path consists of an up, followed by a good path of some length $2a$, followed by a down, followed by a good path of some length $2b$.  Clearly $a+b+1=n$.  That is, for $n>0$: $$C_n=\sum_{a+b=n-1}C_aC_b.$$
Let $C=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^n$.  Then we have $$C=1+xC^2.$$
Thus $C=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$.  Evaluating the Taylor series of $\sqrt{1-4x}$ gives us $C_n={2n \choose n}/(n+1)$.
